# AndroidWear Cinema Mode

Tags: wear-os, lockscreen

Is there a way to programmatically put an AndroidWear device into "Cinema Mode"?

I would like the screen to be locked so that touches don't register on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot programmatically enter theater mode on Android Wear. It has to be done by the user.

However, you can write an AlwaysOn app https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html and then control what is shown on the display. You could render a black background with some simple text, or none at all, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to stop touches on the screen from starting interaction with the watch. The issue is that when I am exercising (in the pool) from time to time the watch face gets long presses on it from water which mean that it goes into select mode for the watch faces.

Ideally I would go into always on in my app but only have the button on the watch enable touch on the screen.

Comment: I'm trying this out but running into a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489361/crash-loading-wearableactivity